# exceljs, как можно скопировать таблицу на несколько листов?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Имеется готовый документ в эксель, в ней есть шапка и заголовки табличной части, вопрос такой, как можно скопировать на новые листы эти данные на node.js?

Массив для примера:

```
const arr = [{number:1, label: 'тут какой-то текст', label2: 'тут какой-то текст2'}, 
 {number:1, label: 'тут какой-то текст', label2: 'тут какой-то текст2'}
 {number:2, label: 'тут какой-то текст', label2: 'тут какой-то текст2'}]
```

Вот получаю нужный мне лист с базовым документом (дальше по коду происходит запись данных в ячейки)

```
workbook.xlsx
 .readFile(fileName)
  .then((e) => {
    const sheet = e.getWorksheet('Лист1')
  })
```

Фильтрую массив arr по полю number, в итоге я должен получить первый лист с название 1 с данными из объектов, которые содержат number: 1, второй лист с именем 2 и соответственными данными.

Завис в непонимании как перенести базовую структуру документа на каждый новый лист.